# The report definition for report '[Report Name]' has not been specified

Tags: c#, rdlc

I am trying to add a reportviewer to my WPF application. I've followed the steps on [This Site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh273267.aspx) but now I am getting this error:

`An error occurred during local report processing. The report definition for report 'ConSegReport' has not been specified. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Here is my code:

```
private void Reportviewer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_IsReportViewerLoaded)
        {
            Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource reportData = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource();
            Consolidated_DBDataSet conSet = new Consolidated_DBDataSet();
            conSet.BeginInit();

            reportData.Name = "ConSegSet";
            reportData.Value = conSet.Cnsldtd_Performance_tbl;
            this.reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportData);
            this.reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "FP Reporting Dashboard.ConSegReport.rdlc";

            conSet.EndInit();

            Consolidated_DBDataSetTableAdapters.Cnsldtd_Performance_tbl_CLONETableAdapter conAD = new Consolidated_DBDataSetTableAdapters.Cnsldtd_Performance_tbl_CLONETableAdapter();
            conAD.ClearBeforeFill = true;
            conAD.Fill(conSet.Cnsldtd_Performance_tbl_CLONE);

            reportViewer.RefreshReport();

            _IsReportViewerLoaded = true;
        }
    }
```

I have also set the .rdlc file to "Copy if newer" for the Output Directory.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried referencing an embedded report always one that was uploaded to SSRS.

Here is my code, maybe it will help:

```
IReportServerCredentials irsc = new CustomReportCredentials(rc.report_ssrs_username,
    rc.report_ssrs_password, rc.report_ssrs_domain);
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = irsc;
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = rc.report_ssrs_path;
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new System.Uri(rc.report_ssrs_url);

SqlConnectionStringBuilder conString = new Database().conBuilder;
List<ReportParameter> parameters = new List<ReportParameter>();
parameters.Add(new ReportParameter("ConString", conString.ConnectionString));
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(parameters);
DataSourceCredentials dsc = new DataSourceCredentials();
dsc.Name = ReportViewer1.ServerReport.GetDataSources()[0].Name;
dsc.UserId = conString.UserID;
dsc.Password = conString.Password;
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetDataSourceCredentials(new DataSourceCredentials[] {
    dsc });

ReportViewer1.ShowCredentialPrompts = false;
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();
```

Let me know if you have any question about what I have here.  We have a single table that defines all of our reports and query off that to dynamically render the reportviewer control.

Just as a side note I would use an underscore naming convention for the RDLC file.  That could trip up code if it's not accounted for correctly.  Also try referencing it will a full path to verify this isn't a relative path issue if it's trying to reference the file from the debug or release directory.

Answer (score 0):

"FP Reporting Dashboard.ConSegReport.rdlc" change it to "FP_Reporting_Dashboard.ConSegReport.rdlc"